# (URI::InvalidURIError) "bad URI(is not URI?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am running a ruby on rails app in the production environment and my ruby version is 1.8.7 and rails version is 3.2.0.
But when ever the URL gets bigger or some one hits that URL I will get a error msg and here is the back trace of the error log.

```
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:436:in `split'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:485:in `parse'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:275:in `open_http'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:616:in `buffer_open'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:164:in `open_loop'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `catch'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `open_loop'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:132:in `open_uri'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:518:in `open'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
 app/controllers/home_controller.rb:107:in `import_items'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:32:in `open_uri_original_open'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:32:in `open'
 app/controllers/home_controller.rb:106:in `import_items'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
 activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:461:in `_run__738958071__process_action__908136048__callbacks'
 activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `send'
 activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
 activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `send'
 activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
 activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
 activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
 activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
 newrelic_rpm (3.3.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:34:in `process_action'
 newrelic_rpm (3.3.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:255:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
 newrelic_rpm (3.3.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
 newrelic_rpm (3.3.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:250:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
 newrelic_rpm (3.3.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:33:in `process_action'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `action'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
 rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `call'
 rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `recognize'
 rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:89:in `optimized_each'
 rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
 rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
 newrelic_rpm (3.3.1) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `call'
 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bundler/gems/exception_notification-7b77a4ea1a61/lib/exception_notifier.rb:31:in `call'
 spree_core (0.50.2) lib/middleware/seo_assist.rb:23:in `call'
 spree_core (0.50.2) lib/redirect_legacy_product_url.rb:10:in `call'
 warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
 warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
 warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
 rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
 activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
 activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
 activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
 activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
 activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'
 activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
 rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
 actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
 railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
 rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
 rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
 rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
 railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
 railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
 railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:205:in `start_request_handler'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `send'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `handle_spawn_application'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rack_application'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rack_application'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
 passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
 passenger (3.0.7) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following sentence from Rails Guide.

**"Note that Ruby 1.8.7 p248 and p249 have marshaling bugs that crash Rails. Ruby Enterprise Edition has these fixed since the release of 1.8.7-2010.02. On the 1.9 front, Ruby 1.9.1 is not usable because it outright segfaults, so if you want to use 1.9.x, jump on to 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 for smooth sailing."**

It is better to upgrade ruby version(1.9.2).